# Microsoft Graph API - Embed Calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

Is there a way to generate or publish the html link of user's calendar using Microsoft Graph REST API?. We are planning to embed it in our page and can't find it on their documentation or maybe it just has a different name. The link I am talking about is the link you can generate in `Outlook Calendar > Settings > Calendar > Shared Calendar > Publish a calendar`

Comment: Programmatically, you can pull the calendar records using Microsoft Graph API, so it's doable. Using that you may want to come with your own UI or sharepoint webpart, publish the same, so that you can re use the sharepoint webpart(embed the calendar) in your application.

Comment: If you talk about Outlook UI publish the calendar then here is the [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-your-calendar-in-outlook-on-the-web-7ecef8ae-139c-40d9-bae2-a23977ee58d5)